# Netbeans doesn't recognize ruby gems installed using Terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, rubygems

I have installed a GEM called "Ziya" using the terminal in Mac OSx. However, when I open the application using the Netbeans, it says that the GEM cannot be found.

If I install Ziya using the GEM manager, I get the following error and the GEM doesn't get installed,

```
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
      /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/snehal/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
```

UPDATE: The GEM is installed in my machine. But Netbeans can't recognize it.

Thanks,
Snehal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do u have the appropriate permission to write to the folders? try to do a

```
sudo gem install Ziya
```

and see if it works =)

Comment: The GEM is installed in my machine. But Netbeans doesn't recognize it.

Comment: it could be that NetBeans can only pick up gems installed in /Library/... directory, which can only be installed if you have the permission and using sudo. Alternatively, you can try to set GEM_PATH and see if it works